# How can I Serialize Microsoft Office objects in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, apache-poi, ms-office

I am trying to find a way to serialize MS Office objects in some way so I can send them to other Java clients without the need of the actual file.

**For example,** I have one client with a MS Word Document within object A. I can already write out and represent object A as an XML, but I want to now have object A's XML contain a serialization of the MS Word Document.

Is this possible with any existing libraries? I am looking at Apache POI, but have not used it for this purpose. I have only used it to read and write Office objects.

**EDIT: See the answer I posted for how I was able to achieve this by using Base64 encode and decode.**

Comment: If you have the office file, and need the same office file at the other end, why not save the messing about and just send the raw bytes of the file over?

Comment: Agreed. And in case message itself is textual (XML, JSON, CSV), just Base64 encode the binary content.

Comment: Define 'MS Word document within object A'. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @gagravarr I didn't know I could do that. So would something like this approach work then? https://gist.github.com/utkarsh2012/1276960

Comment: @EJP just means I have an object that has an internal ms office object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to Gagravarr for the idea, I ended up using Apache commons to base64 encode and decode the file. I followed the example in this link.

http://blog.icodejava.com/248/how-to-base64-encode-or-base64-decode-a-file-in-java-using-apache-commons-codec/